# Thymeleaf não exibe data no componente HTML5

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Olá!
Estou começando a estudar thymeleaf junto ao Spring MVC e me deparei com um problema que não consigo resolver.

Tenho um campo de data com o componente `type="date"` do HTML5 em um formulário, o qual funciona 100% ao cadastrar. Porém, quando uso o formulário para edição, todos os dados do formulário são exibidos em seus componentes HTML, menos a data.

Ao analisar o código-fonte do HTML da página a data está lá, mas não aparece no componente visual.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="data" name="data" value="03/03/1985">
```

Quando uso JSP/JSTL sempre que o formulário abre para edição a data no componente do HTML5 já aparece no input, porém não está aparecendo com o Thyemeleaf.

Alguém sabe o motivo e como resolver? Esse é meu input:

```
<input th:field="*{data}" type="date" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o problema. Eu tinha criado uma classe do tipo Formatter para formatar a data e parece que esse foi o problema. Ao criar essa classe eu removi a anotação `@DateTimeFormat` do atributo de `LocalDate`.
Acabei então removendo a classe Formatter e voltando com a anotação citada. E para formatar a data na página, eu utilizei a dependência

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Registrei ela na configuração do Template Engine

```
templateEngine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
```

e na hora de exibir data formatada na página

```
<td th:text="${#temporals.format(user.data, 'dd MMM yyyy')}"></td>
```

Dessa forma consegui então formatar a data para exibir na página e também a questão da data no campo date do input.